# Converting an ASCII string to USB UTF16 string format expresses as shell string using shell command

Tags: shell

I could do this on my head with python or C or Java but after going through dozes of google hits I can't make a start on how to do this with shell commands in a script.

Background:

I've got a (serial) number that I need to convert into a UTF16 string which I will then pass to a utility (HEXMATE) that will plunge it into an Intel hex file. The final format of the string in memory is USB string i.e. two byte length (LSB,MSB) and then all the string characters as UTF16 characters (LSB,MSB). The utility only accepts a string which it will plunge as is (plus null) to the given memory address. Hence I need to embed the string length to the beginning of the string using escapes.

Is this even doable in a script?

I know by now I could have solved this with many other means but I don't want to bring in new tools (outside say posix or MacOs) and I would like to learn how to do this with a script.

So how do I turn "ABC" to "\003\000A\000B\000C000\" using shell tools?

For simplicity we can assume the serial number is ASCII and not longer than 255 characters.

Comment: You wrote: `"\003\000A\000B\000C000\"` — presumably, you needed the last backslash before the last three zeros: `"\003\000A\000B\000C\000"`?  What are the constraints on the (serial) number?  Digits and Latin alphabet?  Is the length variable?

Comment: did you try iconv  command?

Comment: How will you pass the converted string to the HexMate utility?  It's not going to be feasible in a shell string because of the embedded null bytes.  It can be put into a file.  The really tricky part is getting the length encoded.  Using: `printf "^CABC" | iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16LE` generates the bytes you need (where I typed control-V control-C to get the length of 3 into the string shown as `^C`).  But I've not worked out how to convert the number.  Is there a reason to think any of your platforms is missing Perl?  If they all have Perl, use it.

Comment: Good point about the null characters, so maybe not doable like I envisioned. Perl is there and python is there (always) so no I could use that.

Comment: ...more thinking, I think it will not be possible to pass that string as string (pun intended). So options are, use the -SERIAL argument instead of -STRING argument for HEXMATE, more verbose but doable. Or use sed to simply replace those few bytes in the hex file.

Comment: the more I think about the more I like the idea of using sed or something like that. The question the comes converting the serial number string to an Intel hex record and replacing one line of the .hex file. If I restrict the serial number to 7 digits then this is a clean one line replacement.

Convert ABC to 650066006700 prepend with 0300, pad with FF to 16 bytes and embellish with Intel hex format stuff (added spaces for clarity):

:10 7FF0 00 3000650066006700 FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF XX

and use sed to find :

:107FF000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF91

and replace that with the string.

Comment: oops, bad spacing but you get the picture...

Comment: Look hard at the [HexMate manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/manual_std952.pdf) (Section 5.15).  The command line expects hex in the `-FIND=` and `-REPLACE=` arguments, which avoids all the issues with null bytes (`00` is perfectly OK on the command line; HexMate should do the conversion to the null byte).  So, I think you're over-complicating things.  You could generate "0300410042004300" as the hex sequence for 'count 3, letters A, B, C' in hex a lot more easily than futzing with the control characters and nulls.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I had overlooked that. Probably because I could not make even the example codes from the manual work. Hexmate does not like me. By now I've solved the real issue with python and sed, took me all of a 15 minutes. I will offer that as an answer but won't accept it; maybe it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen from comments this it is probably not possible to do exactly what I asked for. However the underlying actual programming problem I've solved with little python and sed.

here is my shell script:

```
SRC="firmware.hex"
DST="firmware.hex-with-serialno.hex"
SERNO=`python serialno.py`
REPLACE=":107FC000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC1"
sed "s/$REPLACE/$SERNO/g" <$SRC >$DST
```

and here is serialno.py

```
file = open("serialno.txt","r")
serno = int(file.readline())
file.close()

serno = serno + 1

file = open("serialno.txt","w")
print >>file, serno
file.close

t="107FC0001003"
for c in '{:07d}'.format(serno):
    t += '{:02X}'.format(ord(c))
    t += '00'

s = 0
for i in xrange(0, len(t), 2):
    b = t[i:i+2]
    s += int(b,16)
s = (-s)&0xFF

t = ":" + t + '{:02X}'.format(s)
print t
```